# why is the code written is having overflow error when executed

Tags: c++

The program is to find  the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143.It is working perfectly for any given no that is   less than the max_int.

Iam running the code in code blocks.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    unsigned  long long a =600851475143 ,prime=2,i,j;
    for(i = 1;i < a/2;i++) {
        int count =1;

        if( (a%i)==0) {
            for(  j = 2;j <=(i/2);j++)
                if(i%j==0)
                    count = 0;

             if(count == 1)
                 prime = i;

        }
    }
    cout<<prime;        
}
```

expected result is the greatest prime factor of 600851475143
but the ouput is nothing,just blank screen

Comment: So what did you see when you debugged your code?

Comment: Always use braces (`{}`) for any flow control blocks.

Comment: You should format and debug your code in order to find your problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Concerning your type of problems, you need to extract a [mcve] before asking here, to weed out bad questions and find simple faults yourself.

Comment: The claim "...it is working perfectly for any given number that is less than max_int" is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

I think you get a time overflow, you are doing a minimum of 600851475143 / 2 operations, which is actually a lot considering that 1 mil. of operations are executed roughly in ~ 0.1s;
You could optimize it a little bit by going not to a/2 but to sqrt(a), more about why here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test)

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    unsigned long long a = 600851475143 ,prime = 2,i,j;
    for(i = 1; i*i < a; i++){
        int count = 1;
        if((a%i) == 0){
            //check if i is prime
            for(j = 2; j*j <= i && count;j++)
                if(i%j == 0)
                    count = 0;
            if(count == 1){
                prime = max(prime,i);
            }
            //check if a/i is prime
            count = 1;
            for(j = 2; j*j <= a/i && count;j++)
                if(a/i%j == 0)
                    count = 0;
            if(count == 1){
                prime = max(prime, a/i);
            }
        }
    }
    cout << prime;
}
```

now we will have around 1 mil. of operations executed by first for.

Also it would be great to check if a/i is also prime because a number coul